# Changing SelectedIndex in ComboBox - Object Required Error

Tags: vba, visio

I have a series of combo boxes that I am using to change text on some other objects in Visio. I'd like to put in a reset button that clears all text as well as sets the index of all combo boxes back to 0. I can clear the text fine, but when I try to set the index of any combo box back to 0, I get

> Run Time Error '424' Object Required.

```
C1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

I can't figure out what it's unhappy about, as I had no problem setting up the combo box with the following code:

```
Dim index As Integer

    C1.AddItem (" ")
For index = 22 To 53
    C1.AddItem ("J" & CStr(index))
Next index
    C1.AddItem ("J66")
    C1.AddItem ("J67")
```

I'm completely new to VBA and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `C1.ListIndex = 0`

Comment: Changing to C1.ListIndex = 0 gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: In my main document, I set up all of the combo boxes as shown in the OP.
Then, immediately below that in the same document, I have the code for the reset button: Private Sub ResetButton_Click()

C1.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub

Comment: You didn't change it to `ListIndex`? There is no `SelectedIndex` in VBA. Are you using forms? or Active-X comboboxes?

Comment: Sorry, just changed it. Now I'm getting Invalid Sheet Identifier. 

This is all being done in Visio, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Well that's progress at least, so now your question has changed. You need to address a different problem.

Comment: Changing to ListIndex fixed it, the Invalid Sheet Identifier was an unrelated error. Thank you so much for the help!